# Check condition of all values in a vector

Tags: r

Question -> Build a condition to check if all the numbers in the vector marks (passed as arguments) are greater than 90. If yes, assign the string "Best Class" to the variable ans, else assign "Needs Improvement"

Answer ->

```
classmark<-function (marks) { # Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output

ans<-ifelse (c(marks) >90, "Best Class", "Needs Improvement")

return(ans)

}

print(classmark (c(100,95,94,56))) 
print(classmark (c(100,95,94,96)))
```

Output :

```
[1] "Best Class" "Best Class" "Best Class" [4] "Needs Improvement"

[1] "Best Class" "Best Class" "Best Class" "Best Class"
```

Complied successfully
But no test cases passed
It shows hidden test cases are failing

Answer (score 2):

You are being asked to check if *all* the numbers in the vector are greater than 90.
Here you can lean on the fact that `TRUE` will evaluate to 1, and `FALSE` to 0. As such, you can check if the sum of the `TRUE` cases are equal to the length of the input. If this is the case, all marks are greater than 90.

Also note that it is not necessary to explicitly call `return` in R, but I included it to match your attempt more closely.

As for reading from `STDIN`, I will leave that part for you to figure out, as this is likely homework.

```r
classmark <- function(marks) {
  
  pass = ifelse(marks > 90, TRUE, FALSE)
  
  ans = ifelse(sum(pass) == length(marks), "Best class", "Needs improvement")
  return(ans)
}

classmark(c(100, 95, 91))
#> [1] "Best class"
classmark(c(100, 95, 80))
#> [1] "Needs improvement"
```

Alternatively you can accomplish the same task with `all`, which checks if all conditions are met:

```
classmark <- function(marks) {
  
  ans = ifelse(all(marks > 90), "Best class", "Needs improvement")
  return(ans)
}

classmark(c(100, 95, 91))
#> [1] "Best class"
classmark(c(100, 95, 80))
#> [1] "Needs improvement"
```

<sup>Created on 2021-12-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

As we are doing your homework here ;)
It is not asked for a function, so there is no need for that.

This would suffice to meet all criteria given in the question.

```
marks <- c(100, 95, 94, 56)
ans <- ifelse(any(marks <= 90), "Needs Improvement", "Best Class")
```